# Partial View Permission in Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having two partial view which are rendered on page,

```
  @{Html.RenderAction("SalesDashboard", "Dashboard");}
  @{Html.RenderAction("MarketDashboard", "Dashboard");}
```

Then in my controller

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult SalesDashboard()
        {
            return PartialView("_SalesDashboard");
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult MarketDashboard()
        {
            return PartialView("_MarketDashboard");
        }
```

This works fine. Now I want to check if the user has permission to view that partial view. So I want to check in my ActionFilter OnActionExecuting.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
 if (filterContext.IsChildAction) //How to get the partial view request here, I mean the controller name and action method
                    {
                        //business logic
                    }
                    int reqCnt = SessionMenu.Menus.FindIndex(i=> i.AccessPath == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
                    if (reqCnt <= 0)
                    {
                      //business logic
                    }
    }
```

I want to get the partial viewrequest path in my filter. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Please check the updated action filter,

```
if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
                    {
                        string cName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
                        string aMthod = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
                        int i = SessionMenu.Menus.FindIndex(item => item.AccessPath == "/"+ cName +"/"+aMthod );
                        if (i <= 0)
                        {
                            filterContext.Result = null;
                        }
                    }
```

filterContext.Result is null when the user don't have permission for the partial request, but the partial view still loads. What should I check in my controller/ view to hide/ prevent loading the partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the partial action name in

```
filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
```

and the partial controller name in

```
filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
```

and the "main view" datas can be found in 
`filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteDate` for example

**EDIT**

Then, to skip execution, you may do

```
filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
return;
```

instead of `filterContext.Result = null;`

Comment: thanks, step ahead now if a user don't have permission to view _MarketDashboard, how should I do it?

Comment: I mean now I get the controller and action name, I can check this against my db. Now how should I prevent displaying a partial view if user don't have permission to view?

Comment: @JohnyBravo I don't know how you manage your permission, but you could also do this in you PartialViewResult, no ? And return null if user is not allowed. You may also try a `return;` in the `OnActionExecuting` if the user is not allowed.

Comment: please check the updated question, I am checking the permission for the user and setting the filterContext.Result = null, how to prevent partial view to load?

Comment: Edited the "skip execution" part.

Comment: Sorry but what does this mean?

Comment: see the "EDIT" in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the controller and action name in your filter you can do this:

```
string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
```

Answer (score 0):

ChildActions are excuted within an action. you also used Attribute ChildActionOnly this made it non usasable until that action on which these childacions have will execute. So you just need to secure your main action.

If you want to render child actions based on permission than you need to handle it on view like this :

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("RoleName"))
{
    @Html.RenderAction("SalesDashboard", "Dashboard")
  @{Html.RenderAction("MarketDashboard", "Dashboard");}
}

@if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("RoleName"))
{
  @Html.RenderAction("MarketDashboard", "Dashboard");
}
```

Comment: the security is not based on Role, it is for user and that too based on the url he is trying to access. If i need to put this logic in the view, then it will be a lot, I mean I need to check the Controller name, action method inside view. I have all the links which user can access stored in session. Can you guide on this?

Comment: You can see I have checked the user permission for parent view, like
 int reqCnt = SessionMenu.Menus.FindIndex(i=> i.AccessPath == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
                    if (reqCnt <= 0)
                    {
                      //business logic
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/InvalidRequest/Display");
                    }